# DocuSignJSON.approveTabs

Tags: docusignapi, docusignapextoolkit

I am trying to use the DocuSignJSON Approve Tabs in Salesforce APEX Class but I am getting the error and I am not sure what is wrong in the code:

Compile Error: Invalid type: DocuSignJSON.approveTabs at line 237 column 9

And here is my code:

```
DocuSignJSON.approveTabs ApproveTab = new DocuSignJSON.approveTabs();
ApproveTab.anchorString = 'APPROVER:';
ApproveTab.buttonText = 'APPROVE';
ApproveTab.height = '18';
ApproveTab.width = '60';
ApproveTab.anchorXOffset = '3';
ApproveTab.anchorYOffset = '0.2';
ApproveTab.anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent = 'false';
ApproveTab.anchorUnits = 'cms';
```

Comment: anchorUnits should be Units could be pixels, millimeters, centimeters, or inches, what is cms? and I think you need to add recipientId also in the tab.

Comment: cms can be used for centimeters and yes, I am adding the recipientID too in my code below. The issue is somehow when the code compiles, it throws the invalidType error.